# Can you combine std::recursive_mutex with std::condition_variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std, recursive-mutex

Can you combine `std::recursive_mutex` with `std::condition_variable`, meaning do something like this:

```
std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> lock(some_recursive_mutex)
some_condition_var.wait(lock);
```

If it's not allowed, then why not?

I am using VC++11.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can, if you use `std::condition_variable_any`, which allows for any type of object that supports the Lockable concept.

However, in the case of recursive mutex, you do have to ensure that the given thread has only locked the recursive mutex once, since the condition variable only will use the `unlock` method on the `unique_lock` once during the wait.

Comment: "you do have to ensure that the given thread has only locked the recursive mutex once" -> which means you cannot use a condition on a recursive mutex, doesn't it? I mean the purpose of a condition is to synch with other threads, and that won't work if the mutex is not guaranteed to be unlocked during the wait.

Comment: @HugoMaxwell It depends on your use case.  If you know you are only 1 level deep in your locks, then you can use it with the condition.  For example, if the recursive nature of the mutex is only used on the signaling side of the condition, it will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with a `std::condition_variable_any` which can take any kind of lockable but plain `std::condition_variable` is specialized for `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`.

Comment: This answer needs more up votes!